# Angular não reconhece variavel dentro de uma function Javascript, integração com o PagSeguro

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Estou consumindo o serviço do PagSeguro em uma aplicação Angular versao 10.2 e estou tendo esse problema:

Dentro de uma função no meu componente eu chamo um objeto do tipo `PagSeguroDirectPaymen`t, e eu não consigo acessar nenhum objeto fora para pegar o `response`.

```
hashPayment: string;

getHashPayment(){

  PagSeguroDirectPayment.onSenderHashReady(function(response){
    if(response.status == 'error') {
      return false;
    }

    //Nesse caso ele reconhece o this como um objeto do tipo PagSeguroDirectPayment
    this.hashPayment = response.senderHash;
    
  });
}
```

Como eu poso passar o `response.senderHash` para a minha variável `hashPayment` do componente?

O script do pagseguro eu coloquei no arquivo `index.html`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
 src="https://stc.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/pagseguro/api/v2/checkout/pagseguro.directpayment.js"> 
</script>
```

e no meu componente eu o declarei assim

```
declare var PagSeguroDirectPayment: any;
```

Obs:
Eu até consigo se eu declarar a variável como `static`, e acessar ela dentro da function colocando o nome do componente mais a variável `static`, só que nesse caso eu não conseguiria usá-la para exibir no meu arquivo `.html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta assim

```
PagSeguroDirectPayment.onSenderHashReady((response)=>{
 if(response.status == 'error') {
  return false;
 }

//Nesse caso ele reconhece o this como um objeto do tipo PagSeguroDirectPayment
this.hashPayment = response.senderHash;

});
```

ou assim

```
const that=this;
PagSeguroDirectPayment.onSenderHashReady((response)=>{
  if(response.status == 'error') {
     return false;
  }

     //Nesse caso ele reconhece o this como um objeto do tipo PagSeguroDirectPayment
    that.hashPayment = response.senderHash;

  });
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Eduado ! Fiquei horas quebrando a cabeça com isso rsrs